# Method: Loop Through Arguments with Defaults

Tags: ruby, constructor, instance-variables, splat

I am building a Ruby object that has defaults for arguments in its `initialize` method:

```
attr_accessor :one, :two, :three

def initialize(one: nil, two: nil, three: nil)
  @one = one
  @two = two
  @three = three
end
```

As you can see, this isn't very DRY, especially as the number of initializable variables grows. Ultimately, I would like to be able to loop through each of the arguments and assign an instance variable (some combination of a splat operator and `instance_variable_set`?), but always have a defined list of expected instance variables with defaults if they aren't defined.

Comment: will you also be adding attr_reader for these vars?

Comment: Yes, thanks for mentioning! Updated example above!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically having an initialize method require a whole bunch of arguments usually leads to the use of an options hash rather than splat.

With an options hash you're able to dry up your initialize method, set instance variables and attr_readers in a very ruby way:

```
class Animal
  def initialize(opts = {})
    options = defaults.merge(opts)
    options.each do |k, v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
      self.class.send(:attr_reader, k)
    end
  end

  private

  def defaults
    {
      type: nil,
      age: 100,
      name: "Unknown"
    }
  end
end

animal = Animal.new(type:'cat', age: 99)
puts animal
puts animal.type
puts animal.age
puts animal.name
```

Output:

```
#<Animal:0x007f9773132650>
cat
99
Unknown
```

Comment: I was actually using an options hash initially, but stopped because I wanted to define all the possible instance variables. I'm realizing now, however that this kinda makes sense as the Ruby way to do this. My concern, however, is trying to access variables that aren't defined at initialization. Am I approaching this wrong by trying to define defaults for all of these variables?

Comment: Sure, that's a common use case and I updated my answer for a way to handle that.

Comment: Yup! Merging defaults seems to be just what I was looking for!